# Gesture Detector in flutter which is not printing a text on screen after tapping

Tags: flutter, encoding, gesturedetector

I am using gesture detector which i have specified the text widget should be printed on screen after tap.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmJTl.png)

Comment: I'm not sure but, did you forget to cal setState() ?;

Answer (score 0):

Firstly its better to use `GestureDetector` as parent widget not in child and secondly, you are using `Text` in onTap function which is not proper، do not use widget inside `VoidCallback` functions like onTap

```
body: GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
        print("tapped");
    }
    child: widget //<-- put container here
)
```